# Google Apps Script Post request external 2-step form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried using the following the following code to 'simulate' a POST request to this form (using 2 steps) https://boekenprijs.cvdm.nl/WVP.Pub/ProductZoeken.aspx

The only required field is the ISBN field. So let's use '9789076174082' for example. When submitting the form it generates another page with the book title. I then need to click on the book title to get the information I need.

How do I get Google Apps script to perform that second step? I've looked at the form source code but haven't been able to figure it out.

I need to fetch the price corresponding to an ISBN. If there is a way to do this in 1 POST request then that would be even better.

This is the code I have so far:

```
 // Make a POST request with form data.

var formData = {
'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_zoekenUitgave$_identificatie': '',
'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24_zoekenUitgave%24_identificatie': '',
'__EVENTTARGET': '',
'__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
'__VIEWSTATE': '',
'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': '',
'__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': '',   
'__EVENTVALIDATION': ''

};


var options = {
'method' : 'post',
'payload' : formData
};

var url = "https://boekenprijs.cvdm.nl/WVP.Pub/ProductZoeken.aspx";

var response   = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);   

Logger.log(response);

return response.getContentText();
```

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to do that with apps script, it's definitely not recommended. What is the final thing you are trying to achieve? I'm sure there are apis that allow you to retrieve a book's title via ISBN

Comment: @Robin Gertenbach I need the price (fixed book price) corresponding to the ISBN. I need that second step to fetch the price. They don't have an API option (yet)